# How to add a shadow to my sharepoint table which resides on my sharepoint wiki page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I use a Wiki page library in Sharepoint. When a new Wiki page is created it appears empty.
Which it can be populated with sharepoint component like: Image, Video, Table etc...
I have put a table on the page which looks in HTML like this:

```
<table class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0" style="width: 50%; height: 1px;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 100% height: 1px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="height: 1px;"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What i would like is to create a border around my table so i have created this css-code:

```
.ms-rteTable-default > tbody > tr > th, .ms-rteTable-default > tbody > tr > td  {
  border: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
}
```

But now i would like to add a shadow on my border: box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rba(0,0,0,0,47);
But where do i have to put the box-shadow code? I have tried everything but no luck :)

Does someone know the answer ?

thank you in advanced.

Greetings. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to add a shadow box for your table!

```
.ms-rteTable-default {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px #CE70F9;
}
```

Or

```
.ms-rteTable-default {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
```

Or at the `table` tag add the `box-shadow` at the `style` as below

```
<table class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0" style="width: 50%; height: 1px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px #CE70F9;">
```

Comment: It works thank you